# I am using Macbook to import pyperclip, but it doesn't work. If I try to install modules, it keeps fail. Hope anyone can help me. Thank you

Tags: python

```
import pyperclip
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in 
import pyperclip
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'

I am using Macbook to import pyperclip, but it doesn't work. If I try to install modules, it looks like the below. Hope anyone can help me. Thank you.

```
pip install send2trash
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
pip3 install send2trash
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Looks like you're typing `pip install send2trash` as python code, but that's the wrong place.  It's a _command_.  Type it at the command prompt.

Comment: I should have typed it into the terminal monitor.

Answer (score 0):

First upgrade pip with the command sudo pip install --upgrade pip.

If the upgrade is successful (a message will show), then install the send2trash package, again with the sudo command, as so sudo pip install send2trash. That should get the job done.